# what are the things need to do in ASP.NET application maintenance project?

Tags: asp.net

I recently got into a project where I need to support for two mobile applications build using asp.net.
Can anybody share the jobs need to do in maintaining those projects ?

Thanks.

Nilesh

Comment: Are you talking about the steps for doing Maintenance Projects ?

Comment: yes. what are the things we do like taking report and what not ?

Comment: I didn't ever handled the maintenance project before, so just need some tips may be

Answer (score 0):

I think you may consider the following points while you are doing maintenance projects :

1) You should talk to your manager and make them understand that you are overloaded and you can't do effective work if everyone keeps bombarding you with requests which they want fulfilled immediately.

2) You should keep tracking on what you have done and how.

3) Keep backups regular basis of all the tasks you have completed.

4) Keep updating your manager on what task you are working and what you have understand and how you want to work/achieve this.

5) Ideally, all incoming requests should be entered into an issue tracker like [JIRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jira_(software)) or [Mantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis). Or at least mailed to the product owner, not you. And he/she should deal with all the complaints from the users too over "why is my request not ready yet?!", allowing you to focus on the development work.

Hope it helps you. :)